# Why didn't the compiler warn me about an empty if-statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-warnings, keil

I'm using [Keil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keil_(company)) µVision v4.74 and have enabled the option "All Warnings".

I wrote the following **intentional** code:

```
if(condition matched)
{
  // Do something
}
```

When I rebuilt my project, I got 0 errors, 0 warnings.

However, when I **accidentally** wrote:

```
if(condition matched);
{
  // Do something
}
```

I also got 0 errors, 0 warnings.

It was next to impossible for me to find out that a small `;` following the *if* condition was the root of the problem.

Why didn't the compiler treat it as a warning and inform me?

Comment: Why should he? Thats a perfectly well formed and legal statement. Nothing warnable here.

Comment: When i declare a variable and dont use it, he say "variable declared but undefined". Should he say something like "if statement used but no body for if statement?"

Comment: One thing I want to mention here. This is not at all related to `keil`.. in general programming also it will happen.

Comment: i tagged it to keil because i expected someone from keil may be able to tell why or consider this to improve their IDE. I dont want someone using Keil to go through the same problem i went through.    gcc throws a warning as told by @Matteo

Comment: The compiler should output one and only one warning, “You are using c, don’t expect a safety net”.

Comment: @Vector9 I agree, I can't think of any legitimate reason for declaring an `if` statement without a body. Seems like it should warn by default, without requiring you to ask the compiler for extra warnings.

Comment: @IanRingrose: on the contrary, given that the runtime is completely without safety nets for performance reasons, having all the possible static analysis at compile time is extremely desirable.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, then don't user C or C++!    Module 2 would be a lot better option, if you care about safety.

Comment: @ckruczek But... that's exactly what warnings are for.  If it weren't well formed and legal, it would be an error.  Warnings are for things that are legal, but suspicious as likely logic errors.

Comment: Keep in mind that many macro suites create this sort of situation right and left, as bits of code are "commented out" or not based on global macro variable settings.

Comment: @HotLicks That sounds interesting to me because I can't think of a case where it wouldn't make just as much to either 1) "comment out" the `if` block as well, or 2) invert the conditional and make the statement that gets "commented out" an `else` block or something similar. So that situation seems entirely avoidable, but being that I'm not a C expert, maybe there's just things I'm not thinking of.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Consider if I do `if (a) some_dump_macro;`.  If a global flag somewhere turns off `some_dump_macro` then I end up with `if (a);`.

Comment: because keil compiler is not very user-friendly

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's not an error because an empty statement *is* a valid statement; however, since it's certainly suspicious code it's the perfect candidate for a compiler warning - and in fact `gcc -Wall -Wextra` does warn about this:

```cpp
int foo(int x) {
  if(x); {
    return 42;
  }
  return 64;
}
```

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116427-37-l1vpg4/example.cpp: In function 'int foo(int)':
2 : warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
if(x); {
^
```

https://godbolt.org/g/RG1o7t

Both [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) and [Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B) do it too.

GCC 6 is even smarter (well, maybe too much), and takes even the indentation as a hint that something is wrong:

```
/tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler116427-76-1sfy0y/example.cpp: In function 'int foo(int)':
2 : warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
if(x); {
^
2 : warning: this 'if' clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
if(x); {
^~
2 : note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it is guarded by the 'if'
if(x); {
^
```

So, either you don't have the warnings cranked up enough, or your compiler isn't smart enough.

If you don't have the possibility to switch to a more helpful compiler, consider using static analysis tools; for example, in this case `cppcheck` spots the error (when given the `--enable=all --inconclusive` flags):

```
cppcheck --enable=all --inconclusive emptyif.c
```

Output:

```
Checking emptyif.c...
[emptyif.c:2]: (warning, inconclusive) Suspicious use of ; at the end of 'if' statement.
[emptyif.c:1]: (style) The function 'foo' is never used.
```

---

#### Addendum - relevant warnings for various compilers (feel free to update)

To recap, the relevant warning options are:

- **gcc** `-Wempty-body`; included in `-Wextra`;
- **gcc**>=6.0, also `-Wmisleading-indentation` can help; included in `-Wall`;
- **Clang** `-Wempty-body`; included in `-Wextra` too;
- **Visual C++** [C4390](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f1zx4y1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), included in `/W3`

Static analysis tools:

- **cppcheck** `--enable=warning --inconclusive`; included in `--enable=all --inconclusive`

Comment: How much more can you crank Keil up beyond "All Warnings"?

Comment: @Vector9: I don't know, I never used Keil. Besides, it seems like Keil itself is mostly an IDE, what compiler backend does it use? Unfortunately "minor" compilers for embedded platforms often lag way behind "mainstream" compilers in this kind of diagnostics.

Comment: My keil uses Armcc.exe v5.03.0.76

Comment: @Vector9: giving a quick look to the list of warnings supported by armcc there doesn't seem to be anything related to this issue. However, I see that Keil [does support](http://www.keil.com/arm/gnu.asp) using `gcc`, so you may give it a try (maybe not in production, but just from time to time to have a look at a different set of compiler diagnostics). But again, I'm no Keil/armgcc expert, so I don't know if can be used mostly as a drop-in replacement or if it is going to be a nightmare to switch between compilers.

Comment: Yup, MSVC warns: `warning C4390: ';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?`. It's actually a [level 3 warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f1zx4y1.aspx), so you don't even need /W4. The default warning level will catch this one.

Comment: Is there an analogue flag for `clang` that would produce this warning?

Comment: @mucaho: `-Wextra` includes it even in clang; the specific flag for this warning is the same as for `gcc`, i.e. `-Wempty-body`.

Comment: Lint will warn about the unexpected change in indentation as well.

Comment: @davenpcj Suggesting the use of a linter may be worth posting as an answer, since it (presumably) wouldn't require switching compilers.

Answer (score 4):

As [Matteo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482904/why-didnt-the-compiler-warn-me-about-an-empty-if-statement/37483139#37483139) indicated, the code is absolutely valid.
It's being interpreted this way:

```
if(condition)
    ;  // do nothing

// unrelated block
{
    // do something
}
```

It's a bit of a technicality, but conditions with empty bodies do have some very nice uses.

Lint and other such code sanity tools will warn about the unexpected change in indentation, and catch additional errors that may be stylistic though not technically compiler errors.

Or security problems, variable tainting, buffer management, potential maintenance problems like bad casts, etc. There are an awful lot of code problems that don't fall into the category of "compiler errors".

As [jpmc26 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482904/why-didnt-the-compiler-warn-me-about-an-empty-if-statement#comment62480913_37483139), this approach may be better since you don't have to switch compilers to use it. Though I also personally find value in the ability to run the two independently.